# How to work with navigation properties (/foreign keys) in ASP.NET MVC 3 and EF 4.1 code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I started testing a "workflow" with EF code first.
First, I created class diagram. Designed few classes - [you can see class diagram here](http://i54.tinypic.com/2n7hxrc.png)
Then I used EF Code First, created EntsContext..

```
    public class EntsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Iteration> Iterations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
```

Next step was creating a ProjectController (ASP.NET MVC3) with simple action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new EntsContext())
    {
        return View(db.Projects.ToList());
    }
}
```

The problem is: I am not getting a ProjectManager in view (List/Create scaffolding used). I would like to know if I am doing this wrong or scaffolding generation just ignores my properties, that aren't basic types.
Hmm... It is probably quite obvious.. because generator doesn't know  what property of that Type should be used, right?

Well then I could modify my question a bit: What's a solid way to create a Project entity in this scenario (I want to choose a project manager during project creation)? Should I make a ViewModel for this?

Comment: In your controller you are returning a list of Projects.  What does your project class look like?

Comment: You can see the class in a linked image containing class diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProjectManager` will not be loaded by default. You must either use lazy loading or eager loading. Eager loading will load `ProjectManager` when you query `Projects`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new EntsContext())
    {
        return View(db.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManager).ToList());
    }
}
```

Lazy loading will load `ProjectManager` once the property is accessed in the view. To allow lazy loading you must create all your navigation properties as `virtual` but in your current scenario it isn't good appraoch because:

- Lazy loading requires opened context. You close context before view is rendered so you will get exception of disposed context.
- Lazy loading in your case results in N+1 queries to DB where N is number of projects because each project's manager will be queried separately.

Comment: Thanks, just a minor modification.. Include() is accepting only string input - name of property, so I have rewritten that to:  `Include("ProjectManager").  Also thanks for hints why not lazy loading in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need a ProjectManager class, and your Project entity will need to have a property that points to the ProjectManager class.

Something like:

```
public class Project
{
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public Member ProjectManager {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Assume that his Project class looks like you described.  How do you get the auto generated view to show the 'Member' property by way of a textbox or something?  I always just do this manually because it seems that there is no way for the wizard to do it for you.  Once you start getting into more complex classes you can't expect the IDE to drill down in to every single property and produce a textbox, can you?

Comment: Check the linked class diagram image. I already got that I believe.